# Anyway to use Terminal to locate this file?

Tags: php, macos, terminal, pear

I downloaded and installed PEAR Auth package using the following on my terminal

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/pear install Auth
```

I got confirmation that it is installed, but when I  do a `require_once('Auth.php')` in the program I am running I'm getting an error message that it failed to include.

When I look in the directory for the auth.php, I can't see it anywhere, but, as I said, I have confirmation it's not installed.

a) because PEAr comes installed with MAMP, I was under the impression that Pear auth.php woulded sync automatically with PHP so that I don't have to build a file path. Is that correct?

b) Is there code that I can enter into the Terminal to find out the file path of auth.php? assuming that it's installed...

Comment: Looks like you're on a Mac, so try `mdfind Auth.php` or `mdfind -name Auth.php`.

Comment: Try with `find / -name Auth.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd [Installation_Dir]
find . -name Auth.php -print
```

This should show you if that file exists in the installation directory.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
Locate Auth.php
```

This would list all the locations of files matching this name..